# How retrieve many disjunct colors for an algorithm clustering application?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, color-scheme

I'm programming a tool, where you can investigate multiple clustering algorithms.

[image: Single Linkage Clustering Result]

This for example is a result for a Single Linkage Clustering.

Now I't wondering, how I could use for example chroma.js or something to create as many **different** colors as possible, **but equally distributed over the color space**!.

Note: Whitish and Blackish colors should be avoided, since the background color is white and the standard dot color is black.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: `Math.random()` will be your friend in this endeavor.

Comment: this result is already done with Math.random().. it rather want I equally distribution of the Colors.. I dont exactly get that with random.. unfortunately

Comment: Use HSL colors, changing the hue value by `360/numberOfColors`.